# Geany cannot find project file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, python3

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Creating a new project in geany, I get message project project file could not be written.  The project is a python 3 project.

I was able to save geany created python script to the project file directory.

Why can't geany find the project file?

I did find a work around.  I copied an old project file and edited it.  Under [projects] I replaced name="old project name" with "new project name" and then also under [projects] I replaced base_path="old project base path" with "new project base path" and stored this where I wanted the project information in the new file structure.  This still does not explain why geany could not create the new project.

Comment: Did you / Geany have write access in the location where it complained "could not be writen"... or what was the exact error?

Comment: Yes, both Geany and I have write permission.  Geany was able to save a file to the directory.  The message was project file could not be written.

Comment: How about in the project files path? It *might* be ~/projects, but should be a setting in Prefs -> General -> Startup

Comment: I checked the preferences and they were pointing to the correct files, and it does save files to these directories, but cannot create the profile.